# Llamada desde contenedor docker a equipo windows local

Tags: docker, conexión

Estoy intentando realizar una llamada POST desde una aplicación java dentro de un contenedor docker, hacia un servicio que se encuentra fuera del dicho contenedor y fuera del ambiente docker. Este servicio al que intento acceder, está en la misma máquina windows donde se encuentra instalado docker, es decir es una conexión hacia fuera del contenedor en dirección hacia la máquina local de windows. El mensaje de error que devuelve es:

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: (connect refused)

La llamada es:

http://localhost:9090/services12/module13/

Utilizando la IP local del equipo windows tampoco me permite la conexión y mismo error

http://192.168.1.34:9090/services12/module13/

Tengo la posibilidad de acceder el servicio sin usar docker y si funciona, por lo que hay algo que está denegando la conexión, ¿Alguna idea de como permitir la conexión?

Un saludo

Comment: `localhost` no te sirve porque sería interna al contenedor. La forma correcta es usar la IP de windows. No obstante, si eso tampoco funciona, seguramente es porque el servidor windows está escuchando en la IP `127.0.0.1` (o `localhost`). Cambia el servidor windows para que escuche en la IP `0.0.0.0` y ya deberías poder acceder al servidor en `192.168.1.34`, tanto desde windows, como desde docker, como desde otra máquina en la misma subred

Answer (score 1):

La solución es poner como máquina de destino "host.docker.internal":

http://host.docker.internal:9090/services12/module13/

Un saludo